# VS Code with Prettier/ESLint uses wrong indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-eslint

Prettier in VS Code uses the wrong indentation, even after I changed all the places I can think of to a width of "4".

Here are my file contents (some are maybe not necessary, but I added them while trying to fix it):

*c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.prettierrc.js*

```
module.exports = {
  semi: true,
  trailingComma: "none",
  singleQuote: false,
  printWidth: 120,
  tabWidth: 4,
  endOfLine: "auto",
  trailingComma: "none"
};
```

*c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.editorconfig*

```
indent_size = 4
```

*c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.eslintrc.js*

```
module.exports = {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        sourceType: "module", // Allows for the use of imports
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true // Allows for the parsing of JSX
        }
    },

    settings: {
        react: {
            version: "detect" // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
        }
    },

    extends: [
        "plugin:react/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
        "plugin:prettier/recommended", // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. This will display prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
        "prettier"
    ],

    rules: {
        // Place to specify ESLint rules. Can be used to overwrite rules specified from the extended configs

        // e.g. "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "no-var": "error", // preference for let and const only
        "prefer-const": "error",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "prettier/prettier": [
            "warn",
            {
                semi: true,
                trailingComma: "none",
                singleQuote: false,
                printWidth: 120,
                tabWidth: 4,
                endOfLine: "auto",
                trailingComma: "none"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

*c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.vscode\settings.json*

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "jestrunner.jestCommand": "npm run test -- --watchAll=false"
}
```

My VS Code configuration is set to "4,", and in the bottom bar in VS Code it's set to "4". I also set "detect indendation" to false.

Here is what the Prettier extension output says when I format the document:

```
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Formatting file:///c%3A/Users/jp/Documents/Repositories/Game/Client/src/App.tsx
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Using config file at 'c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.prettierrc.js'
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Using ignore file (if present) at c:\Users\jp\Documents\Repositories\Game\Client\.prettierignore
["INFO" - 17:18:30] File Info:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "typescript"
}
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Detected local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig), VS Code configuration will not be used
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Prettier Options:
{
  "filepath": "c:\\Users\\jp\\Documents\\Repositories\\Game\\Client\\src\\App.tsx",
  "parser": "typescript",
  "semi": true,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "singleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "tabWidth": 3,
  "endOfLine": "auto"
}
["INFO" - 17:18:30] Formatting completed in 0.027ms.
```

It even says it found the right configuration file, yet uses the wrong indentation.
I restarted VS Code while making the changes to make sure nothing was cached.
In the parent path no .editorconfig is present.

I just don't have any idea where Prettier may take the wrong indentation from...

Edit: When I use the "Quick Fix" with "Fix all prettier/prettier problems", it uses the correct indentation. Formatting on save or Using "Format document" uses the wrong one. Output of the extension output window is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your detect indentation has been enabled. Disable it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious at first, but prettier has order of reading custom configs and is this one according to [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html):

> Prettier uses cosmiconfig for configuration file support. This means you can configure Prettier via (in order of precedence):
>
> 1. "prettier" key in your package.json file.
> 2. prettierrc file written in JSON or YAML.
> 3. .prettierrc.json, .prettierrc.yml, .prettierrc.yaml, or .prettierrc.json5 file.
> 4. .prettierrc.js, .prettierrc.cjs, prettier.config.js, or prettier.config.cjs file that exports an object using module.exports.
> 5. .prettierrc.toml file.

I can only assume you forgot to check configuration in package.json, and remove these settings from there.